# Little blank space between toolbar and settings bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, toolbar

I have a strange issue that i cannot solve, i have a little spacing between my settings bar and the toolbar, [watch here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZgXI.png)

**my xml for the toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

**on activity i call it like this:**

Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

All Acitivity XML (put all my code in external file and include it)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.afcosta.inesctec.pt.android.FamilyLibrary"
    android:paddingTop="6dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:backgroundTint="#f1c40f"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="562dp"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/custom_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Familias"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:textSize="24dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

it appears, but that strange white space is annoying :/

Comment: put all your activity xml here

Comment: watch now, i change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove padding from `ConstraintLayout`:

```
  android:paddingTop="6dp"
```